# Assembly program to shift a string with given number of characters

Tags: assembly, x86

The task is the following:
There is a given string from the alphabet for example *fgh*. I have to shift this string with *n* letteres with the given direction. For example, if the direction is 1, and *n=3* the output would be *ijk*. I have created a program which could calculate these shifts, but if it reaches the end of the alphabet it would write the the following characters in the ASCII table. For example, if the input is *vwy* the output would be *yz{*. There is a code snippet that I currently have:

```
loop1: ; if the direction is forwards
        MOV AL, [ESI]
        CMP AL, 0
        JE end

        ADD AL, 3
        INC ESI
        Call WriteChar
        LOOP loop1
loop2: ; if the direction is backwards
        MOV AL, [ESI]
        CMP AL, 0
        JE end

        SUB AL, 3
        Call WriteChar
        INC ESI
        LOOP loop2
```

Could you help me out, and show me how can I modify this code to work with the input (*xyz*, n=3) above?

Answer (score 0):

When "shifting" "upwards", after you have modified the character, you need to compare it against the last character in the alphabet, and if it has exceeded that value, then you have to do something with it.  What to do with it should have been specified in the definition of the "task", bit it probably involves wrapping around the alphabet, so, essentially, subtracting 26 from it.

When "shifting" "downwards" you need to do the opposite: compare the newly calculated character against the first character in the alphabet, and if it is below that, then add 26 to it.

"Coding this in x86 assembly is left as an exercise to the student."

Comment: shouldn't it be 26 ? ;)

Comment: @Tommylee2k wh00ps, yes, 26.  I fixed it.

Comment: `26 == ('z'+1-'a')`, if you are lazy to count those letters... (may not work with some very simple assembler, but most of the x86 assemblers happily compile ASCII char literal into correct numeric value)